# CGImageDestinationCreateWithData not creating a CGImageDestinationRef object

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, automatic-ref-counting, core-foundation

I'm sure this is something simple, but I just can't find it.

I am trying to create a `CGImageDestinationRef` using the `CGImageDestinationCreateWithData` function, but its returning me a nil.

Function documentation:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGImageDestination/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGImageDestinationCreateWithData

The function is pretty simple but I can't seem to get it to return me an object. I'm in an ARC class so there is a bridging wrapper around the function.

My code snippet:

```
NSMutableData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
CGImageDestinationRef imageDestination = nil;

imageDestination = (__bridge CGImageDestinationRef) CFBridgingRelease(CGImageDestinationCreateWithData ((__bridge CFMutableDataRef)data, (__bridge CFStringRef)type, 1, NULL));

if (!imageDestination)
    NSLog(@"This is always called. :-(");
```

I would greatly appreciate any help from someone who spots me doing something stupid!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've solved it and am posting the answer here as it may help someone else in the future.

I have a type set to be @"image/jpg", which did not seem to work (documentation suggest it should).

When I changed the type to @"public.jpeg", the function started to work as expected.

Using Jim's hint in the comments below, this is what I ended up doing to find the correct UTI type from a URL:

`NSString *uti =  CFBridgingRelease(UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag(kUTTagClassMIMEType, (__bridge CFStringRef)[NSString stringWithFormat:@"image/%@", url.pathExtension], kUTTypeImage));`

Comment: If you have a MIME type such as `image/jpeg` then you can use the UTI API (import `<MobileCoreServices/MobileCoreServices.h>`) to sort it out: `NSString * uti = CFBridgingRelease(UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag(kUTTagClassMIMEType, (__bridge CFStringRef)mimeType, NULL);`. The last parameter can narrow down the match too: pass `kUTTypeImage` to say you expect an image type, for example.

Comment: Thanks Jim. Handy function there.

Comment: Hehe, didn't recognize you there :o) Look in EPUBProtocol.m or AQHTTPResponseOperation.m and you'll see us using that to get a MIME type from a file extension. Very nice & useful API.

Comment: Instead of manually constructing the MIME type (and assuming the file extension will be a valid MIME type component), you could use CoreServices to do the path extension to UTI conversion directly: `UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag(kUTTagClassFilenameExtension, (__bridge CFStringRef)url.pathExtension, NULL)`